# Rspec any_instance stub causing error undefined method __rspec_original_dup

Tags: ruby, rspec, stub

I'm trying to stub out a Class method for any instance of the class (via any_instance). My tests run through successfully, but at the end of the test when rspec is trying to reset the any_instance stub, it throws an error (Unable to find matching line from backtrace). Here's the apparent culprit line of code (removing it removes the error):

```
Confetti::Config.any_instance.stub(:write_info)
```

The full error is below. Seems like stub should've (but fails to) created the __rspec_original_dup method, and when the reset happens, it can't find the expected method.

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NameError:
   undefined method `__rspec_original_dup' for class `Confetti::Config'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-mocks-2.11.1/lib/rspec/mocks/any_instance.rb:73:in `alias_method'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-mocks-2.11.1/lib/rspec/mocks/any_instance.rb:73:in `restore_dup'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-mocks-2.11.1/lib/rspec/mocks/any_instance.rb:72:in `class_eval'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-mocks-2.11.1/lib/rspec/mocks/any_instance.rb:72:in `restore_dup'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-mocks-2.11.1/lib/rspec/mocks/any_instance.rb:46:in `rspec_reset'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-mocks-2.11.1/lib/rspec/mocks/space.rb:17:in `reset_all'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-mocks-2.11.1/lib/rspec/mocks/space.rb:16:in `each'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-mocks-2.11.1/lib/rspec/mocks/space.rb:16:in `reset_all'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-mocks-2.11.1/lib/rspec/mocks.rb:23:in `teardown'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/mocking/with_rspec.rb:18:in `teardown_mocks_for_rspec'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:308:in `run_after_each'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:119:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:253:in `with_around_each_hooks'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:110:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:378:in `run_examples'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:374:in `map'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:374:in `run_examples'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:360:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:361:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:361:in `map'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:361:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `autorun'
 # /usr/bin/rspec:19
```

Comment: Looks like you're using OSX system Ruby. Does it work if you use RVM or rbenv?

I ask because we're seeing the same behavior, but only for devs running OSX system Ruby.

Comment: Getting something similar after upgrading to RSpec 2.11. I use Ruby 1.9.3 from RVM, though on OS X, if that has any relevance. I do `ThinkingSphinx::Search.any_instance.stub(:error)` and get the error `undefined method \`dup' for class \`ThinkingSphinx::Search'` with this in the backtrace: `/Users/henrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-patched@foobar/gems/rspec-mocks-2.11.1/lib/rspec/mocks/any_instance.rb:64:in \`alias_method'`.

Comment: Created an issue: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/168

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by simply using Rspec v2.10.0 instead of v2.11.0:

```
gem 'rspec', '~> 2.10.0'
```

From the links that Henrik provided, it sounds like they may release a bugfix for Rspec.  Watch [this issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/168) for more information.  In the meantime, downgrading solved the issue for me.

(Thanks for your work in helping me figure this out, Henrik.)